# Why does this Java code implicitly calls toString() method?

Tags: java, printing, tostring, implicit

Why is the output? : Sphere 0

Somehow it's calling the toString() method implicitly? How does this work ?

```
class BerylliumSphere {
    private static long counter = 0;
    private final long id = counter++;
    public String toString() { 
        return "Sphere " + id;
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        BerylliumSphere spheres = new BerylliumSphere();
        System.out.println(spheres);
    }
}

// output: Sphere 0
```

Comment: There is no magic and it's not "Java" that does it, but the `println` method. You can implement such a method yourself. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/io/PrintStream.java#820

Comment: Passing object in println() always gives the toString representation

Comment: This is not "implicit", it is "explicit", just look what `println` does.

Comment: @Tom Hey tom it is implicitly calling because I never called the toString() method in the main method so it happens internally.

Comment: @TimothyKimman Just because you don't call it, it means that this is implicit. The call of `toString()` is explicitly done in the source of `String`.

Comment: Implicit is stuff defined by the JLS, like abstract methods in interfaces are *implicitly* `public` even if one doesn't add an access modifier, or that `super()` will *implicitly* called in a subclass constructor if not done explicitly.

Comment: Thanks, also kudos for JLS reference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`System.out` is a `PrintStream` instance that is a static member of `System`. The `PrintStream` class has a function `println()` that accepts an argument of type `Object`. That function, in Open JDK, looks like the following:

```
public void println(Object x) {
     String s = String.valueOf(x);
     synchronized (this) {
         print(s);
         newLine();
     }
}
```

And if you look at `String.valueOf()`, which accepts an argument of type `Object`, you can see:

```
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}
```

There is no magic. It's just a Java class that calls `toString` on objects.

**Further Reading**

- Take a look at the docs for the PrintStream class: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html

Comment: But I don't get why it is using the toString() method I wrote in the BerylliumSphere class since I never called it?

Comment: You need to learn about Polymorphism my friend! By creating your own toString(), you have overridden the implementation of the same function in all superclasses.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what `System.out.println` does: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28java.lang.Object%29

It says the following:

> This method calls at first String.valueOf(x) to get the printed
>   object's string value, then behaves as though it invokes print(String)
>   and then println().

And here is what `String.valueOf` does: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Object%29

And it says:

> If the argument is null, then a string equal to "null"; otherwise, the
>   value of obj.toString() is returned.

In short, printing an object will result in calling its `toString` method and printing what it returns.

Comment: But I don't get why it is using the toString() method I wrote in the BerylliumSphere class since I never called it?

Answer (score 1):

When you try to `System.out.println(spheres)` it looks like following:

```
public void println(Object x) {
        String s = String.valueOf(x);
        synchronized (this) {
            print(s);
            newLine();
        }
    }
```

And this is `valueOf(Object obj)` method:

```
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
        return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
    }
```